# Is it possible to create a generic Map swapper?

Tags: apex, map, deserialize, serialization, generics

I have a method:

```
public Map<Object, Object> swap(Map<Object, Object> valueByKeyMap) {
    Map<Object, Object> keyByValueMap = new Map<Object, Object>();
    for (Object key : valueByKeyMap.keySet()) {
        Object value = valueByKeyMap.get(key);
        if (!keyByValueMap.containsKey(value)) {
            keyByValueMap.put(value, key);
        } else {
            throw new XAP_UTIL_MapManyToOneException(
                    'Swap can only be used for maps with one-to-one relationships.  '
                            + ' Conflicting values: '
                            + ' Existing mapping for ' + value + ': ' + keyByValueMap.get(value)
                            + '; new mapping for value: ' + key + '.'
            );
        }
    }
    return keyByValueMap;
}
```

I'd like to be able to reuse this solution for any Map whose keys are the same type as the value.  For example, `Map<String, String>` or `Map<SObjectField, SObjectField>`

I thought of doing this:

```
public Map<String, String> swap(Map<String, String> valueByKeyMap) {
    Map<Object, Object> retypedMap = (Map<Object, Object>) JSON.deserialize(
            JSON.serialize(valueByKeyMap), Map<Object, Object>.class
    );
    Map<Object, Object> swappedMap = this.swap(retypedMap);
    return (Map<String, String>) JSON.deserialize(
            JSON.serialize(swappedMap), Map<String, String>.class
    );
}
```

But:

1. Serialize/Deserialize is computationally expensive.
2. System.JSONException: No mapping for apex type: Object;
3. System.JSONException: Apex Type unsupported in JSON: Schema.SObjectField

Would there some other way to approach this without creating duplicate code for any required map types?

Comment: It's essentially the exact same issue as your previous question.

Comment: Similar, but worse.  Here it isn't even possible to use serialize/deserialize to solve (whereas, even though nobody suggested it and I didn't mention it), the previous question is actually solvable with serialize/deserialize if I don't mind the computational expense.   Also, here I am more interested in building up a reverse index.  It's not so important for me that it is a Map although the type safety would be a plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, this isn't exactly the answer I am looking for.
It isn't really a Map and isn't completely interchangeable with a Map.
However, this is a generic solution which effectively reverse indexes maps.
And the bulk of the code is entirely reusable, although we would need a new constructor to support each Map Type:

```
public class XAP_UTIL_MapReverseIndexer {
    List<Object> keyObjectList;
    List<Object> valueObjectList;
    public XAP_UTIL_MapReverseIndexer(Map<String, String> valueByKeyMap){
        this.keyObjectList = new List<String>(valueByKeyMap.keySet());
        this.valueObjectList = valueByKeyMap.values();
    }

    public XAP_UTIL_MapReverseIndexer(Map<Double, Double> valueByKeyMap){
        this.keyObjectList = new List<Double>(valueByKeyMap.keySet());
        this.valueObjectList = valueByKeyMap.values();
    }

    public XAP_UTIL_MapReverseIndexer(Map<Integer, Integer> valueByKeyMap){
        this.keyObjectList = new List<Integer>(valueByKeyMap.keySet());
        this.valueObjectList = valueByKeyMap.values();
    }

    public XAP_UTIL_MapReverseIndexer(Map<SObjectField, SObjectField> valueByKeyMap){
        this.keyObjectList = new List<SObjectField>(valueByKeyMap.keySet());
        this.valueObjectList = valueByKeyMap.values();
    }

    private Map<Object, Object> keyByValueMap {
        get{
            if (this.keyByValueMap == null) {
                this.keyByValueMap = this.buildKeyByValueMap();
            }
            return this.keyByValueMap;
        }
        private set;
    }

    public Object get(Object value) {
        return this.keyByValueMap.get(value);
    }

    private Map<Object, Object> buildKeyByValueMap() {
        Map<Object, Object> keyByValueMap = new Map<Object, Object>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < this.keyObjectList.size(); i++) {
            Object key = this.keyObjectList[i];
            Object value = this.valueObjectList[i];

            if (!keyByValueMap.containsKey(value)) {
                keyByValueMap.put(value, key);
            } else {
                throw new XAP_UTIL_MapManyToOneException(
                        'Swap can only be used for maps with one-to-one relationships.  '
                                + ' Conflicting values: '
                                + ' Existing mapping for ' + value + ': ' + keyByValueMap.get(value)
                                + '; new mapping for value: ' + key + '.'
                );
            }
        }
        return keyByValueMap;
    }

}
```

Note: I don't know how reliable this solution is.

As of Summer '15, the keySet() and the values() to be [predictable](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_apex_maps_and_sets_iteration_order.htm)  ([Thanks, @David Reed!](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260773/do-maps-have-an-reliable-relationship-between-keyset-order-and-values-order)), there doesn't seem to be any guarantee these will always correspond.

(For the moment, this seems to work... tested with Strings, Integers, Doubles, SObjectFields...)

Answer (score 1):

We don't have [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), like we do in Java, so you would be stuck writing our own custom Map class in order to implement this algorithm, and perhaps methods to convert to/from this class to actual maps.

Comment: If I were to sacrifice the type safety of Map for this approach, would there be any to write a reusable conversion method?

Comment: @BrianKessler regrettably not (mostly). The runtime itself only allows limited conversions. A few generics for sobject/object might work, but you'll only have limited functionality for that effort.